# Terraform - can modules have a Subversion source?

Tags: svn, terraform

I don't see Subversion listed as a source for Terraform modules here:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/sources.html

Is it possible to use Subversion?

I don't see any documentation on this.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this writing, Terraform does not support Subversion as a first-class module installation source. If you have modules in Subversion then at present it would be necessary to have some sort of build process package them up as archive files (e.g. `.zip` or `.tar.gz`) and then reference the archive files as the module source.